# Constructor inheritance problems c

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, abstract-class

If my base class's constructor takes parameters, how do I create a class that inherits from it, and executes the base class's constructor using the derived class's constructor?

For example, assuming my base class's instructor takes an integer, and does a cool trick with it, how would I make it so all classes that inherit from it can do the same

Pseudo-code

```
baseClass instance(99); //does an awesome trick, nice
derivedClass instance(99); //<-- should do the same as above
```

As I have it now, I have my base class's constructor defined, but for the derived class, I left its constructor blank, since I want it to do exactly what the base constructor does, and nothing more. But, this gave me an error along the lines of: no matching function call to the 'baseClass()', candidates are: baseClass(int), candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Do I have to make the base class's constructor virtual or something?

Comment: edit: that was bad information. Update: you use `derivedClass() : baseClass(7){}`

Comment: Use a [member initialization list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361).

Comment: Also, unless `base` contains a pure virtual function, you should remove the `abstract-class` tag.

Comment: Well what if the base class's constructor alters the instance of the base class that uses it? Will it also alter the instance of the derived class? @Dave

Comment: @user1538301, alters how? There is no valid instance until after the constructor is run.

Comment: @remyabel yeah, I originally had a question about abstraction that I removed. I was going to ask if I made the base class abstract, and just moved the constructor's implementation into the derived classes would that work. Well, I figured it would, but it wouldn't be the best way to do things I think, since I'd be copypasting the same code for every single derived class

Comment: @StoryTeller Variable initializations. For instance if you pass x and y into the base class, it by default sets the base class's x and y coordinates to those passed in.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy in the current C++ standard, but it still requires some action on your part:

```
struct baseClass
{
  explicit baseClass(int);
};

struct derivedClass : baseClass
{
  using baseClass::baseClass;  // inherit *all* of baseClass' constructors
};
```

In the previous standard, C++03, you have to implement the constructor in the derived type and call the base class's one in the initialization list:

```
struct derivedClass : baseClass
{
  explicit derivedClass(int i) : baseClass(i) {}
};
```

**Note**: I use `struct` here to save typing: default member access and inheritance is `public`.

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote? I would gladly fix this answer if there are any problems.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that `derivedClass` will need to call `baseClass` constructor anyway, since it needs to to complete its construction. The error you get is due to the fact that, without calling a the base constructor explicitly, the compiler is trying to call the default one.

However, in your case, it does not exist, since you already defined a constructor that takes an `int`. To do what you want, a solution could be to do this:

```
class derivedClass : baseClass {
    public:
        derivedClass(int x) : baseClass(x) {}
};
```